Do the merits of an exegesis whose exegete hasn't read the text depend upon whether the exegete couldn't* read the text or wouldn't* read the text?
Couldn't read the text
Well, this at least should be familiar to all of us. There is something awful and powerful in the way it can take half a day to understand a single word, or most of Heinrich Meyer's natural life to explain the grammar, word order and idiom of perhaps half of the words in the NT. Does that flow down from 'no one has ever seen God' (John 1:18)?
Wouldn't read the text
"No, it doesn't say that." "Merit is who said it." "Just let the text flow into you through the dustjacket."
That's hopefully not a default position yet, but online it's commonplace, even though the hazards are obvious in today's world and the scripture.

So that I can continue relating any answers to what people have already explained, if possible, I'd be grateful to keep it that:

The merits of both types of exegesis mustn't be in terms of intent, motive, or purpose; only their end-products

If someone wouldn't read the text, the way their exegesis is evaluated mustn't exclude their exegesis from being improved through appropriate study and dialogue.



Felix - (I have not downvoted this question) - I am distressed about your line of questions here that I have trouble even understanding.  Please remember that the purpose of the Bible is simple to enable sinners 9all of us) to know God and His free salvation by grace.

@Dottard - the easy questions haven't found answers either, but if I've followed what formats I'm given, they should stand until someone recognizes them from their reading. If I can read then I have it within me to answer these things, but it would be rude to do that and unwise as well before bringing them to experts

Felix - I am having trouble even understanding your questions.  you will need to ask them in a clearer way that better relates them to the text of the Bible.

@Dottard it's already being broken down into such small chunks that people's answers lack each other's context and are difficult to piece together. If someone understands, they can help by saying how to express the question in this field's language. But to say both things - well, I only care if the person who answered understood. And if nobody does that's fine too

OK, Felix - let's hope someone will understand the question!

@FelixLXX When you say, "Couldn't read" do you mean, "can't understand" or "incapable of reading"? And when you state, "wouldn't read" do you mean the individual has chosen not to read the text, yet they may still make claims or conduct exegesis based on secondary sources or preconceived notions?

@Jason_ re. 'couldn't read' that's a fine distinction - I mean where some information didn't make it through to them - something like reading Philippians 4:13 as "I can do anything". But about 'wouldn't read' I also meant more partially - so e.g. not reading the word 'doulos' in Luke 19:17 because they only want the landowner to have paid employees. This is still closing off whether motivation matters - wouldn't/couldn't is framed as 2 motivational categories and hermeneutics may cut through that, but what if it finds itself needing to be reasonable with destructive projects. but that is after

"but it would be rude to do that" — No, people that post answers on Stack Exchange sites are allowed to answer their own questions. "and unwise as well before bringing them to experts" — Usually true. If it turns out that other people don't properly understand the question, it's unlikely they'll understand your answer either.

How is someone going to exegete a text without reading it? I don't understand.

To preface. I believe all exegeses should stand as a testament to the pursuit of truth. Just because I believe the answer to be true does not mean that I think the process and approach to exegesis are inconsequential.
Short Answer:

The merits of an exegesis do not inherently depend on whether the
exegete couldn’t or wouldn’t read the text.

Let me explain! In the end, the value of an exegesis is ultimately judged by the quality and insight of the interpretation it provides. This means that we cannot use the circumstances or motivations of the exegete to judge their work.
The truth will be the truth even if the vilest of creatures speaks it.

Case 1: An exegete couldn’t read the text.
Let's say it's due one of these two reasons:

a lack of understanding
a lack of access to information

What would classify as a good exegete under these circumstances? Here's the parameters I would give.
A person would be considered as having done good exegetical work under these circumstances if:



They are transparent about the methods they used (and the lack of sources.)




They acknowledge that they don't understand whatever part of the text they are struggling with. (We are humans, and we have limitations.)




They actively seek out clarification by being open to learning from others rather than the text.




They may state their opinion but should let it be known that it is an opinion that may lack the necessary components to assess the probability of its accuracy.




Case 2: An exegete wouldn’t read the text.
Let's say it's due one of these two reasons:

willful ignorance
confirmation bias

Willful ignorance:

A decision in bad faith to avoid becoming informed about something so
as to avoid having to make undesirable decisions that such information
might prompt. [1]

Confirmation bias:

people’s tendency to process information by looking for, or
interpreting, information that is consistent with their existing
beliefs. [2]

To be honest, this presents a much more challenging scenario. Why? Because the exegete’s approach is almost entirely characterized by a deliberate decision to avoid engaging with the text fully. It's clear that the likelihood is high that this can, and likely will, lead to a skewed interpretation.
A person would be considered as having done good exegetical work under these circumstances if:



They are transparent about the methods they used.




They acknowledge in their exegeses that they have not made a conscious effort to consider all relevant aspects of the text including those that may be uncomfortable or contradictory to their views.




They may state their opinion but should let it be known that it is an opinion that may lack the necessary components to assess the probability of its accuracy.




They should acknowledge when their interpretation is influenced by personal beliefs.



It rather clear that if an exegete chooses to ignore parts or rely on preconceived notions, the exegesis may be flawed from the outset.
This does not preclude the possibility of value!
Here's the ultimate challenge: even if the initial approach was biased or conducted with incomplete information, it still may be true or accurate!

Therefore, I must conclude that

the end-product of the exegesis should be independent of the
exegete’s initial ability, willingness to read the text, personal
biases, preconceived notions, and limitations that may have influenced
its development.

Ideally, we should ask: Does the exegesis provide a plausible, coherent, and authentic interpretation of the text?
